# How to fill in missing values in the dataset using mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

[image]

I have a data set which contains missing values as shown in the image. I would like to fill in the minimum value of the column in place of missing values. Which methods in Mathematica can be used to solve this issue and how can it be done?

Comment: show the code that produced the image

Comment: The data is a replica of original data. It was not generated by any code.

Comment: are you saying you can not produce a one or two line code example ?  Please go read the site documentation "how to ask a question"

Comment: This can be done with `Dataset`. Were you to provide a some  code to produce an example `Dataset` then someone might show you.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to say anything specific, but in general you just need to put your column into a list `l` and take `Min[l]`, then just fill in the missing values manually.